# How to stop training in tensorflow 2 object detection api and start again from the same step?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am using Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API to train a model. I am following the guide [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html). I started the training and every thing is fine but i want to pause the training and feed it more date and start the training again. I am able to start the training but it starts at 0 steps. When I look at the tensorboard I get these weird graph.

With no smoothing: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Monster-Gaming-Studios/hello/7946e5c04bc8f5279cf3f2d239fb15f8f13d67d6/Loss_total_loss.svg

With max smoothing: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Monster-Gaming-Studios/hello/599076669dc1413927e0792904413e45a13203d1/Loss_total_loss%20(1).svg

Am I doing everything right and I should ignore the graph in tensorboard or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Note:- I am a complete noob at tensorflow ao please try to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a **CheckpointManager** at the start as:

```
checkpoint_path = os.path.abspath('.') + "/checkpoints"   # Put your path here
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(encoder=encoder,
                           decoder=decoder,
                           optimizer = optimizer)
ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=5)
```

Now after running for few epoch, to restore latest checkpoint, you should get the latest checkpoint from the `CheckpointManager`:

```
start_epoch = 0
if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
    start_epoch = int(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint.split('-')[-1])
    # restoring the latest checkpoint in checkpoint_path
    ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
```

This will restore your session from the latest epoch.

Now, if you add more data in between this, then you may get higher losses in the start. Just make sure that all the data are relevant to your model, then run for some epochs and you may see converging results.

Comment: Top one- before starting training for the 1st time

Comment: Then stop your training when you want. Nextly, Before starting next training, run the bottom code snippet.

Comment: Then if you want to stop and start again, just run the bottom one in advance to load latest epoch

Comment: The code will access the checkpoint_path, so you should store checkpoint_path folder, maybe in drive. When colab session expires, it deletes every folder. So, you should keep this seperately.

Comment: You should not store it in training script, It itself stores it's data in checkpoint_path. But if you change your model, or some model parameters such as number of neurons or layers, then it will give an error, then you should delete the path and create again using the 1st code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/issues/98, you can simply restart the training process.  This worked for me with TensorFlow v2.

E.g.

```
python /path/to/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=/path/to/prev/dir ...
```

The key is to have a startup script which points to the same `model_dir` directory that you used before.  And, as @Rahul Vishwakarma mentioned, if you change the model or pipeline parameters, you could get errors or unexpected results.